# Turn based Number game

Tags: strategy, game, calculation-puzzle, game-theory

You and a friend take turns saying positive integers greater than one. You can't say a number that is a multiple of previous numbers or a sum of multiples of previous numbers. For example, if A says 3 and B says 7 then A cannot say 17, because 17=2*7+3. If you are unable to say a number you lose.

One way to lose is by starting off saying the number 2 or 3; then the other person says the one you didn't say and when it comes back to your turn you lose (2 and 3 can make any positive integer greater than 1).

What are some strategies, how do you win?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is the

> [Sylver coinage game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylver_coinage). The example winning strategy there is to say 5, 7, 11, 13 etc. as a first move <s>(diagram coming soon for 5)</s> Diagram cancelled - see [this](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=R1sAvfl9Lo8C&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=hutchings+theorem+sylver&source=bl&ots=r3hkZcp1oV&sig=XSlK-dlMiio5fuSDCs9DCzELydI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSzoGUst_UAhXNNpQKHcg0D74Q6AEIUDAH#v=onepage&q=hutchings%20theorem%20sylver&f=false)
>
>
>  "Unlike many similar mathematical games, sylver coinage has not been completely solved, mainly because many positions have infinitely many possible moves. Furthermore, the main theorem that identifies a class of winning positions, due to R. L. Hutchings, guarantees that such a position has a winning strategy but does not identify the strategy. Hutchings's Theorem states that any of the prime numbers 5, 7, 11, 13, …, wins as a first move, but very little is known about the subsequent winning moves: these are the only winning openings known."
>
>
>  -- Wikipedia